# Jenkins delete jobs when branch deleted via branch-indexing

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-2

Is there a way to tell Jenkins (2.2) to remove jobs for branches that were deleted? Currently my build-monitor fills up with branches as the jobs are not deleted. Is there a setting to trigger this behavior or should this be filed as a bug?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you are using latest Jenkins version, consider switching your jobs to [multibranch pipeline setup](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/).

> The Workflow Multibranch feature (provided by the workflow plugin) provides the following key abilities:
>
> - Automatic Workflow (job) creation in Jenkins per new branch in the repo (assuming webhooks are registered from GH to Jenkins).
> - Build specific to that child-branch and its unique scm change and build history.
> - **Automatic job pruning/deletion for branches deleted from the repository, according to the settings.**
> - Flexibility to individually configure branch properties, by overriding the parent properties, if required.

**EDIT**: check the 'Discard Old Items' settings for you pipeline. If you have non-zero 'Max # of old items' then, if your branch had less builds then this number, it will never be deleted! You can even see that in logs:

```
Will not remove US12345 as it is only #1 in the list
Will not remove US23456 as it is only #2 in the list
Will not remove US34567 as it is only #3 in the list
```

**EDIT**: You can also try your luck by adding additional behavior named "Prune stale remote-tracking branches" ("Behaviors" -> "Add" -> Select from dropdown).

Comment: So I will consider it a bug as I am using the multibranch pipeline setup - thanks

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing...the old branches aren't deleted from Jenkins when they're gone from the repository.  @ligi: did you file a bug?

Comment: Note that he current version of the Multibranch PIPELINE Plugin has a setting for deleted branches (and merged PR's) under "Orphaned Item Strategy" which offers a different policy than for the branches that are still active. I believe this would be the correct answer as of today.

Comment: I am fighting this also, I though it was working, on the UI the pruned branches are no longer there, but on the disk the jobs are still there, the disk usage keep climbing. I can't get jenkins to automatically delete the items from disk

Comment: This is still a major issue.

Comment: Any news on this as of today?

Comment: I had this problem and it was due to no Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers being set, as described in https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66970

Answer (score 6):

1) Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Git -> Add Git -> Choose JGit`.

2) Then go to your multibranch pipeline configuration and choose `JGit` instead `Default` under `Branch Sources -> Git Executable`

3) Press `Branch Indexing -> Run now`

Old branches should go away now

Comment: Where is `Branch Indexing -> Run now` ?