# Catch the event of removing a branch from github webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I need to make my own script to remove the branch on the removal event from the Github. I use multibranch pipeline and Blue Ocean plugin.

Comment: Do you mean Git Lab ??

Comment: @rohitthomas Jenkins

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: Do you need execute some task in jenkins when branch is deleted in github?

Comment: @Igor Since you are using multiBranch Pipeline you dont need to do anything since MultiBranch pipeline works on looking for a JenkinsFile in each Branch so if you delete a Branch from github itself there will be no JenkinsFile to locate since the branch will not be available when a scan is done for a detailed explaination look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210799/jenkins-delete-jobs-when-branch-deleted-via-branch-indexing

Comment: @JRichardsz yes i need execute some task. Because when Jenkins create a branch my task copy code to another directory and when github delete branch i need delete code from this directory. This is done for nginx configuration so that each branch had its own url

Comment: Are you using some webhook configuration in your github ? This could be help you https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks If you want I can help you in your configurations. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have webhooks set up for push events.  You will need to set up a similar webhook, but instead of using the push hook, use a [delete](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#deleteevent) hook, which is fired any time a branch or tag is deleted.